# Python parsing a Markdown, search it and render back to Markdown

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, markdown

I am trying to parse a markdown into a searchable or iterable structure like a tree that i can render back to markdown again in the end.

I want to search for certain nodes in some markdown files and copy these nodes and the contents of that into another markdown and save that other file into back to Markdown.

I haven't really found a lib that can properly do that without the need of an own renderer or giving me proper access to the content. Maybe i am too nooby since i am fairly new to python so i don't know all the good packages yet.

Comment: Please provide some code (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I haven't really found a lib that can properly do that without the need of an own renderer or giving me proper access to the content. Maybe i am too nooby since i am fairly new to python so i don't know all the good packages yet." Please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. We don't do recommendations for tools or libraries here. These are considered [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) projects, not on-topic questions.

Comment: @Beatdown The problem is that i can't provide code since i don't have any code. I have no library to code with which is why i am asking.

Comment: I think even a small example of what the markdown input would include and what your desired/expected output or Python objects (if you did have a program) should look like will help with getting a useful answer.

Comment: @AcademicCoder It's experimental, but give http://humanmark.tkte.ch/ a try.